# C# passing function with variable argument list as an argument

Tags: c#, delegates, parameters

I am trying to hide complexities in functions to make for easy function calls. For example a function `Log(string msg)` for writing text messages to a textbox control, with a newline, and Invoke() for multi-threading. Now I want to avoid having to use `Log(string.Format("..{0}..", x, ...))` and wrote a version of `Log(string format, params object[] args)`, which works great.

Until I need to pass this Log() as an argument to another function that needs to do logging:

```
AnotherFunction(Action<string, object[]> Log)
{
  Log("formatstring", new object[] { value1, value2, ...});
}
```

My question: how can I avoid having to code the `new object[]` construction each time I have to call Log()?

Comment: I don't believe you can and it would happen anyway (an array is created from a params argument). Your only real option would be to have a few overloads with varying number of args.

Comment: For this to work it would have to be possible to define a type Action<string, params object[]>, but the 'params' keyword is only available within function parameter lists, so using a Delegate definition seems to be the only option if you want syntactic sugar for variable parameter list length.

Comment: @JonnyDee: instead of syntactic sugar I would rather see delegates as a new level of complexity. With C, it would have been easier. Perhaps less strong typing, but, to me, easier to understand syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that an interface would be the cleanest solution. If that isn't an option however, you can always create your own delegate that uses `params`:

```
public delegate void FormattingLoggerDelegate(string format,
                                              params object[] args);
```

`AnotherFunction` would look like this:

```
public void AnotherFunction(FormattingLoggerDelegate log)
{
    log("formatstring", value1, value2);
}
```

Usage would be transparent, i.e. no need to cast to your delegate. Just like with `Action` an implicit cast exists:

```
AnotherFunction(Log);
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/3rSEk0)

Comment: Note that this will still create the object array (automatically though).

Comment: Sure, the parameter is an array, so naturally one needs to be created at some point. The question of the OP is about avoiding to have to *type out* the array creation manually.

Comment: I think it can be read in 2 ways, the most likely is your interpretation, the second is that he wants no array construction at all.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: Which would make no sense at all.

Comment: I've had to do it in the past (to do with garbage collection and minimizing creating short-lived objects). That's probably why I initially interpreted his question like that. I agree it's a very rare case.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: I don't see how you can call a method that requires an array without creating one first :-) But maybe I am not understanding you correctly.

Comment: He has control of the method he's calling, so he could change it so it doesn't need an array (i.e. make a few overloads with a varying number of arguments, falling back to the worst case params array for more args.), see my comment on his question. :)

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: Aha, that's where you were headed. That would be a possibility but actually wouldn't directly relate to the delegate. He would have to change the method itself.

Comment: Great solution! +1. This C# can do a lot, but to me it appears that things are sometimes not easy to guess. Thanks for your help. I also like the discussion, which offers additional viewpoints, and shows that I am not alone in this problem.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: I indeed wished to avoid having to type the array creation manually, especially because I need to code lots of calls like this. Less typing means less effort, but also better readibility, fewer bugs, etc.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: I edited my original question to remove the uncertainty that you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

An interface would be cleaner. You might also want to consider using an existing logging framework (such as log4net or NLog), and implement a target (or use an existing one) that writes output to a textbox.